# JS Confirm, false, return, not working

Tags: javascript, confirm

this current piece of script to confirm whether a user wants to log out is not fully working in Safari on Mac.

```
function log_out()
{
    ht = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
    ht[0].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?'))
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        ht[0].style.filter = "";
                return false;
    }
}
```

It works when the user confirm they want to logout, Ok, but when the user clicks cancel, they are still logged out.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function you posted is fine. Where is it called though?

Comment: It's called on the logout link: `<a class="rnavtab" href="?do=logout" onclick="log_out()">Log out</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the **return** instruction in front of the log_out call

```
<a class="rnavtab" href="?do=logout" onclick="return log_out()">Log out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, but when the user clicks cancel,
>   they are still logged out.

After seeing your code in the comment you posted:

```
<a class="rnavtab" href="?do=logout" onclick="log_out()">Log out</a>
```

The `?do=logout` is triggered irrspective of whether a user confirms or not. Try putting a hash instead:

```
<a class="rnavtab" href="#" onclick="log_out()">Log out</a>
```

You can later on redirect user like this:

```
window.location = '?do=logout';
```